# pytorch equivalent tf.gather

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I'm having some trouble porting some code over from tensorflow to pytorch.

So I have a matrix with dimensions 10x30 representing 10 examples each with 30 features. Then I have another matrix with dimensions 10x5 containing indices of the the 5 closest examples for each examples in the first matrix. I want to 'gather' using the indices contained in the second matrix the 5 closet examples for each example in the first matrix leaving me with a 3d tensor of shape 10x5x30.

In tensorflow this is done with `tf.gather(matrix1, matrix2)`. Does anyone know how i could do this in pytorch?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how it's done in TF, but did you check [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.gather)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
matrix1 = torch.randn(10, 30)
matrix2 = torch.randint(high=10, size=(10, 5))
gathered = matrix1[matrix2]
```

It uses the trick of indexing with an array of integers.

Comment: it results in the tensor with shape (10, 5, 30).... is it really working for OP...?

Answer (score 0):

I had a scenario where I had to apply `gather()` on an array of integers.

#### Exam-01

```py
torch.Tensor().gather(dim, input_tensor)
```

```py
# here,
#   input_tensor -> tensor(1)
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
my_tensor = torch.IntTensor(my_list)
output = my_tensor.gather(0, input_tensor) # 0 -> is the dimension
```

#### Exam-02

```py
torch.gather(param_tensor, dim, input_tensor)
```

```py
# here,
#   input_tensor -> tensor(1)
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
my_tensor = torch.IntTensor(my_list)
output = torch.gather(my_tensor, 0, input_tensor) # 0 -> is the dimension
```