# Copying data from one tensor to another using bit masking

Tags: pytorch

```
import numpy as np
import torch
a = torch.zeros(5)
b = torch.tensor(tuple((0,1,0,1,0)),dtype=torch.uint8)
c= torch.tensor([7.,9.])
print(a[b].size())
a[b]=c
print(a)
```

> torch.Size([2])
> tensor([0., 7., 0., 9., 0.])

I am struggling to understand how this works. I initially thought the above code was using Fancy indexing but I realised that values from **c** tensors are getting copied corresponding to the indices marked 1. Also, if I don't specify dtype of **b** as **uint8** then the above code does not work. Can someone please explain me the mechanism of the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing with arrays works the same as in numpy and most other vectorized math packages I am aware of. There are two cases:

1. When `b` is of type `uint8` (think boolean, pytorch doesn't distinguish `bool` from `uint8`), `a[b]` is a 1-d array containing the *subset* of values of `a` (`a[i]`) for which the corresponding in `b` (`b[i]`) was nonzero. These values are aliased to the original `a` so if you modify them, their corresponding locations will change as well.
2. The alternative type you can use for indexing is an array of `int64`, in which case `a[b]` creates an array of shape `(*b.shape, *a.shape[1:])`. Its structure is as if each element of `b` (`b[i]`) was replaced by `a[i]`. In other words, you create a new array by specifying from which indexes of `a` should the data be fetched. Again, the values are aliased to the original `a`, so if you modify `a[b]` the values of `a[b[i]]`, for each `i`, will change. An example usecase is shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53697596/4280242) question.

These two modes are explained for numpy in [integer array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) and [boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing), where for the latter you have to keep in mind that pytorch uses `uint8` in place of `bool`.

Also, if your goal is to copy data from one tensor to another you have to keep in mind that an operation like `a[ixs] = b[ixs]` is an in-place operation (`a` is modified in place), which my not play well with autograd. If you want to do out of place masking, use [`torch.where`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.where). An example usecase is shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53692802/4280242) answer.

Comment: Thanks for explaining

Comment: Can you suggest any documentation for the  behaviour of arrays you explained above

Comment: Found this http://www.math.buffalo.edu/~badzioch/MTH337/PT/PT-boolean_numpy_arrays/PT-boolean_numpy_arrays.html

Comment: [This](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html). The two relevant paragraphs are [integer array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) and [boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing), where for the latter you have to keep in mind that pytorch uses `uint8` in place of `bool`.

Comment: I expanded my answer to also mention `torch.where` which may be the actual solution if you want to copy data between tensors.